# Abrir div ao clicar em uma data

Tags: jquery, html, div

Como eu faço para abrir uma `div` ao clicar numa das datas? Quando clicar em outra a `div` aberta feche e abra a clicada com um conteúdo diferente?

```css
#agenda {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: white;
 position: relative;
}

.link {
 color: orange;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: segoe ui;
 font-size: 70px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.estilo {
 width:300px; 
 height:200px; 
 margin:auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 150px; 
 z-index:200; 
 border-radius: 1px; 
 background-color: rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.9);
 text-align: center; 
 padding:30px;
 color: white;
 font-family: segoe ui;
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: crosshair;
}

.estilo a {
 text-decoration: none;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 80px;
 right: 125px;
 color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#1").click(function(){
           $("#2").fadeToggle();
          });
 
   </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="agenda">
   <div>
     <a class="link" id="1">1</a>
    <div style="display: none;" class="estilo" id="2"><p>Rua tanakomoto - 85, fgffgjgyjf - São Paulo, SP</p><a href="#">Veja no Maps</a></div>
              <a class="link" id="1">2</a>
    <div style="display: none;" class="estilo" id="2"><p>Rua tanakomoto - 45, kjhdsxrjnf - São Paulo, SP</p><a href="#">Veja no Maps</a></div>
              <a class="link" id="1">3</a>
    <div style="display: none;" class="estilo" id="2"><p>Rua tanakomoto - 90, dffsdrgfgs - São Paulo, SP</p><a href="#">Veja no Maps</a></div>
               </div>

  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podes comentar neste jsFiddle o que não funciona? -> http://jsfiddle.net/1r0uo70b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue o link do Fiddle comentado

http://jsfiddle.net/gildonei/z0w8mpkq/

**HTML**

```
<div id="agenda">
    <div>
        <a class="link" id="1">1</a>
        <div style="display: none;" class="estilo" id="2"><p>Rua tanakomoto - 85, fgffgjgyjf - São Paulo, SP</p><a href="#">Veja no Maps</a></div>
        <a class="link" id="1">2</a>
        <div style="display: none;" class="estilo" id="2"><p>Rua tanakomoto - 45, kjhdsxrjnf - São Paulo, SP</p><a href="#">Veja no Maps</a></div>
        <a class="link" id="1">3</a>
        <div style="display: none;" class="estilo" id="2"><p>Rua tanakomoto - 90, dffsdrgfgs - São Paulo, SP</p><a href="#">Veja no Maps</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#agenda {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.link {
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: segoe ui;
    font-size: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.estilo {
    width:300px; 
    height:200px; 
    margin:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px; 
    z-index:200; 
    border-radius: 1px; 
    background-color: rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.9);
    text-align: center; 
    padding:30px;
    color: white;
    font-family: segoe ui;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: crosshair;
}

.estilo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 80px;
    right: 125px;
    color: orange;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#1,#2,#3").click(function(){
        $('.estilo').fadeOut(); // Oculta Todos os Divs
        $(this).next().fadeIn();// Mostra somente o div que está "junto ao link"
    });
});
```

Comment: era exatamente isso, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Para utilização de componentes datas, como você está utilizando jQuery, recomendo que utilize esse seguinte componente [jQuery DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Ele tem o comportamento que você espera